# r pkgdown docsearch algolia

Tags: javascript, r, github-pages, algolia, pkgdown

I am having trouble understanding how to implement the docsearch snippet into my github pages (I am using **bootstrap 3**).

From the [package documentation](https://pkgdown.r-lib.org/articles/search.html#bootstrap-3-algolia):

> 1. Once you have published your pkgdown website, submit the pkgdown site URL to Docsearch. **DONE**
> 2. Put the value of the apiKey and indexName parameters into your site _pkgdown.yml. **DONE**

---

Given my lack of knowledge, I am now having hard time understanding this.

The Docsearch\Algolia emailed me:

> **CSS**
>
> Copy this snippet at the end of the HTML `head` tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@docsearch/css@alpha"/></pre></li>
```

> **JavaScript**
>
> Copy this snippet at the end of the HTML `body` tag

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@docsearch/js@alpha"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  docsearch({

    appId: xxxxxx,

    apiKey: xxxxxx,

    indexName: xxxxxx,

    container: '### REPLACE ME WITH A CONTAINER (e.g. div) ###'

    debug: false // Set debug to true if you want to inspect the modal

  });

</script>
```

**QUESTION:**
Shall I copy these snippets on every html page generated by pkgdown or there is an automatic way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://pkgdown.r-lib.org/articles/customise.html#additional-html-and-files), the best way to include custom HTML like this is to add it to your `_pkgdown.yml` file under these options:

```yaml
template:
  includes:
    in_header: <!-- inserted at the end of the head -->
    after_body: <!-- inserted at the end of the body -->
```

So in your case, you should do something like this:

```yaml
template:
  include:
    in_header: |
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@docsearch/css@alpha"/></pre></li>
    after_body: |
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@docsearch/js@alpha"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        docsearch({
          appId: xxxxxx,
          apiKey: xxxxxx,
          indexName: xxxxxx,
          container: '### REPLACE ME WITH A CONTAINER (e.g. div) ###'
          debug: false // Set debug to true if you want to inspect the modal
        });
      </script>
```

---

Note that this feature was added about 4 months ago, so there's a chance it won't work with Bootstrap 3 or old versions of pkgdown. If this doesn't work, the old way of doing this was to:

- Add a folder called `pkgdown/templates`
- Add `in-header.html` and `after-body.html` in that folder
- Place your CSS code in `in-header.html` and your JavaScript in `after-body.html`
- Rebuild the site

I hope one of these works for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think this may be a good solution. At the moment I am rewriting the source code so I am not able to re-build the site. As soon as I can I'll post an update to state if this solution works.

Comment: You’re welcome. I look forward to hear how it worked for you.

Comment: the includes in `_pkgdown.yml` work on bootstrap 3 pkgdown vs 2.0.2

What shall I put in container: '### REPLACE ME WITH A CONTAINER (e.g. div) ###'

Comment: I’m glad it worked. They probably mean a HTML tag which can be a container. See more e.g. [here](https://flaviocopes.com/html-container-tags/). If you don’t have any prefrences I would set it to `'div'`.